# Service to host streaming videos for mobile access where urls are not trackable

Tags: ios, iphone, youtube, vimeo, http-live-streaming

I'm building an iOS app and Android app that will display a series of private videos. Someone will purchase the app for x amount and then have access to the videos through that app only.

I already know a couple of ways to do that part. But the real trick is hiding the video urls to traffic sniffers/etc. I don't want anyone to be able to detect the video urls, or at least the endpoint will reject a request without an auth token.

So I could build my own Node/Express server, incorporate wowza maybe with Amazon to store the files - but that is a lot of work.

So what is the simplest solution to stream my videos to mobile without people being able to load up the videos outside of the app?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll need to implement some sort of authentication system, so that even if they get the video url somehow, they will be unable to view it without the authentication key.

Your videos should be hosted in a directory on your server that is inaccessible from the web. Then use some sort of index page which takes a parameter for the video ID and does the authentication before serving up the video file contents.

Comment: I can understand that theoretically - but hosting and delivering up my own streaming content and building a whole solution around this is the opposite of what I'm looking for.

Comment: Have you looked into just using youtube or vimeo and setting the videos to be private? https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177?hl=en

Or are you asking how to authenticate with these private videos from inside your app?

Comment: Yeah vimeo has something that will work. Very expensive. I'm kind of reaching for a setup that just doesn't require a full on custom solution. Id rather spend my time on the apps than the back-end.